# Visual Studio 2008 crash on 'Add Items to Folder'

Tags: visual-studio-2008

No luck at MSDN with this one, which is driving me nuts.  I us VS Team System 2008 (w/ Resharper).  Everytime I press the Add Items to Folder button in the Source Control Explorer VS crashes....no error in the App Event log, no crash report popup.
Fortunately I also have VS 2005 (also w/ same version of Resharper) on my box which I can Add Files from... I reinstalled VS 2008...no luck.

VERY frustrating.  I asked MS for some way to identify a crash log somewhere in their files, no response there either, so if someone knows that these exceptions are written somewhere maybe I can find them and work the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Windbg (or ADPlus, or a 2nd copy of Visual Studio) to capture the dump while you reproduce the crash.  Then send that to ReSharper and MS support.

ADPlus is particularly well documented for this exact purpose: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350

edit: as mentioned, make sure you have the latest patches for both VS and ReSharper.  In particular, if you installed SP1 before you installed Team Explorer, you'll need to re-run SP1 in order to bring the Team Explorer binaries up to date.  I do recall there being some compatibility problems with 3rd party plugins that were fixed in SP1.

edit #2: there is also a post-SP1 hotfix that appears to be related - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/f807b02a-4ca3-4f2f-9a4e-dbd2e4ee5690

Comment: I *had* to rebuild my box when Win7 went GA so this issue disappeared for me.  HOWEVER, for anyone else who may encounter this, the link to the binary has finally been released to the public.  Hopefully this would have solved my issue and will solve yours....
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB960096/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2074

Answer (score 0):

You can also just start another VS2008 and attach to the first one in the debugger. You should be able to see what the exception was, and capture any debug output.

---

Also, use Tools->Add In Manager to disable all add-ins and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I ended up needing to uninstall VS2008 and basically my entire setup, reboot, and then reinstall everything to get it working.  I still have no idea why it broke, this is just what I had to do in order to get it fixed.

Comment: It takes almost two days to install my entire dev setup...I opened a ticket with Microsoft on this...I sincerly hope they come back with a better option than a total reinstall of the system.  :)